# Using AWK or SED to Duplicate Lines and Ultimately Create Method Wrappers

Tags: c#, perl, macros, sed, awk

No solution found yet on stackoverflow for this simple question. Some answer it somewhat but I am a newbie at awk and sed.

I would like to create wrappers for my methods in my input code file. It has hundreds of lines that are characterized by these two:

```
   public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status);


   public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status);
```

I would like to convert them to:

```
 public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status)
 {
      return NativeMethods.GetImageType(ref fptr, ref imgtype, ref status);
 }


 public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status)
 {
      return NativeMethods.fiwyhjl(ref fptr, axisx, ref imagetype, ref axisy, ref axisx, ref status);
 }
```

Any ideas on what I can do with awk or sed? As a first step, I would just like to know how to duplicate each line that starts with "public". In that case, the result would look like:

```
   public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status);
   public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status);


   public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status);
   public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status);
```

I can then manually add/modify the rest as required.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this perl one-liner,

```
perl -pe 'print m/(.*);/; s/public int //; s/ref \S+/ref/g; s/(.*);/ {\n\treturn NativeMethods.$1;\n}/' input.txt
```

input.txt contains,

```
public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status);
public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status);
```

will produce following result,

```
public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status)
{
        return NativeMethods.GetImageType(ref fptr, ref imgtype, ref status);
}
public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status)
{
        return NativeMethods.fiwyhjl(ref fptr, int axisx, ref imagetype, ref axisy, ref axisx, ref status);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried it with Strawberry Perl (64-bit) 5.18.1.1-64bit on Windows 8. I received the error "Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1." Any ideas. Sorry I did not mention Win8 sooner. It, of course, may make a difference. Thanks!

Comment: use double quotes, `perl -pe "print m/(.*);/; s/public int //; s/ref \S+/ref/g; s/(.*);/ {\n\treturn NativeMethods.$1;\n}/" input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `sed` or `awk`, but it should be pretty easy with `perl`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace for details. You can double lines something like this:

```
s/^\s*public.*$/\0\r\n\0/ ;
```

You can do transform your declaration thusly:

```
s/(public int GetImageType\(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status\));/\1 { return NativeMethods.\1 ; }/ ;
```

[My perl-fu is a little rusty these days, so I might be a *little* off here and there].

Answer (score 1):

and here is the AWK version,

```
awk '{ header = gensub(/(.*);/,"\\1","g"); print header; body = gensub(/public \w+ (.*);/,"{\n\tNativeMethods.\\1;\n}","g"); gsub(/ref \w+/,"ref", body); print body}' input.txt
```

will produce,

```
public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status)
{
        NativeMethods.GetImageType(ref fptr, ref imgtype, ref status);
}
public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status)
{
        NativeMethods.fiwyhjl(ref fptr, int axisx, ref imagetype, ref axisy, ref axisx, ref status);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Sorry about the newbie follow-up question. I should have included this was on Win8/with gawk at the command line. Do you happen to know the string converted for gawk? I am getting errors at the single and double quotes when trying to run with gawk. Sorry/thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` script:

```
sed  '/^public int/{s_;$__;p;s_\([(,] *\)[^ ]* \([^ ]*\)\([,)]\)_\1\2\3_g;s_\(ref\) [^ ]*_\1_g;s_public int _{\n    return NativeMethods._;s_$_;\n}_;p;d}'
```

will transform:

```
public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status);

public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status);
```

to:

```
public int GetImageType(ref fitsfile fptr, ref int imgtype, ref int status)
{
    return NativeMethods.GetImageType(ref fptr, ref imgtype, ref status);
}

public int fiwyhjl(ref fileFormat fptr, int axisx, ref int imagetype, ref int axisy, ref long axisx, ref int status)
{
    return NativeMethods.fiwyhjl(ref fptr, axisx, ref imagetype, ref axisy, ref axisx, ref status);
```

(Note `int axisx` is correctly changed to just `axisx` in the last line.)

This is admittedly ugly, but perhaps a bit shorter than the awk solution, but longer than perl. How robust is, and whether it will meet the OP's needs, I have no idea. The conversion of `int axisx` to `axisx` takes about a third of it, and is contained in:

```
    s_\([(,] *\)[^ ]* \([^ ]*\)\([,)]\)_\1\2\3_g;
```

where the first of two tokens is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I am not brilliant with AWK but I think this should work:

```
awk '{a=$0;sub(/public int /,"return NativeMethods.",a);gsub(/ref \S+/,"ref",a)};{if ($1 !~ /public/) ORS=RS;else ORS="\n"" {""\n""\t"a"\n"" }""\n\n"}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^(\s*)public\s+\S+\s+(.*)/{h;s//\1{\n\1    return NativeMethods.\2\n\1}/;s/ref\s+\S+/ref/g;H;g}' file
```

Copy lines that begin `public...` to the hold space. Rearrange the current line to fit the appended data, append this data to the copied line then replace the current line with the result.